# useQuery Hook result set to loading without being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm trying to build a search bar in my new project, and I seem to be doing some things(maybe a lot) wrong.

I set the book state to null and the useQuery hook seems to be using it to search for books.

I don't want it to search for anything unless I click the button.

These are my codes:

fetchBooks.jsx

```
async function fetchBooks({ queryKey }) {
  const book = queryKey[1];

  const response = await fetch(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${book}`
  );
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Search not found for ${book}`);
  }
  return response.json();
}

export default fetchBooks;
```

Here is the main component.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import fetchBooks from "../helper/fetchBooks";

const Home = () => {

    const [book, setBook] = useState(null);

    const results = useQuery(["search", book], fetchBooks);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setBook(e.target.elements.book.value);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="book">
                    Book Name:
                    <input type="text" name="book" />
                </label>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

            {results.isLoading ? (
                <div>Loading...</div>
            ) : results.isError ? (
                <div>{results.error.message}</div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <h2>Results</h2>
                    <ul>
                        {results.data.items.map((item) => {
                            return (
                                <div key={item.id}>
                                    <h3>{item.volumeInfo.title}</h3>
                                    <p>{item.volumeInfo.authors}</p>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return a default value in the fetch function if the book is null. Then, the query won't actually request the API.

```js
async function fetchBooks({ queryKey }) {
  const book = queryKey[1];

  if(!book) return { items: [] }

  const response = await fetch(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${book}`
  );
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Search not found for ${book}`);
  }
  return response.json();
}

export default fetchBooks;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of restricting the `useQuery` to call the `fecthBooks` functions, you can modify the `fetchBooks` functions to return an empty array if `book` is set to null. The `fetchBooks` can be modified as below:-

```
async function fetchBooks({ queryKey }) {
  const book = queryKey[1];
  if(!book){
    return { 
              isLoading : false,
              error : null,
              data : null
           }
  }
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${book}`
  );
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Search not found for ${book}`);
  }
  return response.json();
}

export default fetchBooks;
```

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way would be to set the `useQuery` itself to `disabled` (via  the `enabled` property) when your params aren't ready:

```
const results = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["search", book],
  queryFn: fetchBooks
  enabled: !!books
})
```

this will prevent the query function from executing when you have no books.